# Flutter - No Pod File - Developing on Windows

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, podfile

I'm developing a Flutter app on **Windows** using Android Studio. My project doesn't contain a 'podfile' in the ios folder, but I think I need to have one in order to properly handle bluetooth permissions (if this iOS setup guide for the permission_handler package is to be believed...)

- Do I need a podfile in order to use bluetooth on iOS?
- If so, how do I get a podfile into my project?

Thanks for any assistance!

- Expected Flutter to automatically create a podfile
- Tried various commands in the ios folder, such as pod init and pod install

Answer (score 0):

if you do not file a pod file you can create it by,

In your terminal give the command `cd ios`. then

1. pod setup
2. pod init

after that, it'll create a pod file for you.
and yes you have to give permission in the pod file while using permission handler package.

e.g,

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

target.build_configurations.each do |config|
 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0'
  config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
    '$(inherited)',
    'PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH=1',
     ]
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. When I try pod setup I get:
`+ pod setup
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pod:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`